# how to link a product to its variety colored photos in a database

Tags: mysql, flask-sqlalchemy, rdbms

here is the current structure of my database (I am using *Flask-SQLAlchemy*):

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    photos = db.relationship('ProductPhoto', backref='product', lazy=True)
    product_size_colors = db.relationship('ProductSizeColor', backref='product', lazy=True)

class Size(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    size = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=False)  

class Color(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    color = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False) 

class ProductSizeColor(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "product_size_color"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'), nullable=False)
    size_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('size.id'), nullable=False)
    color_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('color.id'), nullable=False)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

class ProductPhoto(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "product_photo"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'), nullable=False)
    photo = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

the current database links the product photos (`ProductPhoto`) to a specific product (`Product`), If the product is a T-shirt that comes in three colors, How can I adjust my database to identify the color of the photo?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to your ProductSizeColor class:

color_rel = db.relationship('Color', backref='product_sc')

And you can then access the color of your T-shirt by using:

```
# instantiate for example some object
product = Product.query.filter_by(name='T-Shirt').first()

# access color of your T-shirt
color_t_shirt = product.product_color_size.color_rel.color
```